# Home button for going back to main activity from my other activities

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

This works perfect to other activities but this does not work for my main activity as it is my Launcher activity .

```
public void OnClickGa() {
    button_ga = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button_ga.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intga = new Intent("com.nizamani.aftabali.metcal.cacal");
                    startActivity(intga);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Back from the Main Activity means `exit my app`.

Comment: i want to go to my main activity from my other activities ..

Comment: So, you want the ActionBar back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exit from an Activity you call finish()

If it's your first activity in the stack (the main) you will exit the application.

Comment: i want to set a home button in my other activities so the user can go back to main screen and select other options from there.